# DRF Permissions: has_object_permission on related models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there is a way, to limit permissions on the related object in Django rest framework? 
For example, I have ticket model instance owned by user:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    # other fields 
    state = FSMField(default=SOME_STATE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="tickets", null=True)

    def allocate(self, by=None):
        # allocate the ticket here
        pass
```

And I want the owner to have access only to `allocate` method.
Figure that I should use `has_object_permission` but don't know how to do it for related objects. 
Also, I can mark all fields except `state` as read only in serializer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As for output, you can override the related field / serializer's `get_queryset` as explained in [that post](https://medium.com/django-rest-framework/limit-related-data-choices-with-django-rest-framework-c54e96f5815e#.m1um2w1u9).

As for input, you should handle the permission in a second validation pass - i.e. after the serializer returned the validated data. You need to raise a `ValidationError` with the error data if needed.